# Recursively parse JSON tree in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I've been stuck with a what I thought was a simple problem in JS. What I'm trying to do is I have an unknown depth JSON like so:

```
"A": {
        "B": {
            "e": "",
            "f": {
                "g": "",
                "h": ""
            },
            "C": {
                "i": "",
                "j": "",
                "k": "",
                "l": ""
            },
            "D": {
                "m": "",
                "n": "",
                "o": "",
                "p": ""
            }...
```

The json can be any level deep. What I'm trying to achieve is create an array of ancestors + itself for each element so for "p" it would be `["A", "B", "D", "p"]`

I tried using recursion like so:

```
build(json, '', []);


function build(json, path, assets){
for (var elem in json) {
  if(json.hasOwnProperty(elem)){
    if(json[elem] == 0){
        assets.push(elem);

          //do stuff with the array


       assets.pop();

      } else {
        var parent = path + '/' + elem;
        assets.push(parent);
        build(json[elem], parent, assets);
        return; 
      }
    }
   }
  }
```

This is a simplified version of the function, the part that does not work correctly. My idea behind it was to go through each element, if it has no children, I append the current element and use it (I don't need to keep the array, just for that use) if it has children, I append the current element and call the method recursively for the current element.

The solution works until it reaches the second level, so for "e", "f", "C", "D" it generates correctly, but stops before going to their children.

What am I missing?

Comment: try removing the return from the code.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite follow your code, so I just wrote a solution from scratch.

Notably, I wasn't sure what the `== 0` check was doing in your code (probably the same thing as my `typeof(...) !== 'object'`?), and I don't understand what `assets` and `path` are meant to do.

```js
var obj = {
  "A": {
    "B": {
      "e": "",
      "f": {
        "g": "",
        "h": ""
      },
      "C": {
        "i": "",
        "j": "",
        "k": "",
        "l": ""
      },
      "D": {
        "m": "",
        "n": "",
        "o": "",
        "p": ""
      },
    }
  }
};

function getPaths(obj, sofar) {
  if (sofar === undefined) {
    sofar = [];
  }

  // Leaf node, just return the path
  if (typeof(obj) !== 'object') {
    return [sofar];
  }

  // Interior node
  var paths = [];
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
    // For each child, recurse and concat
    paths = paths.concat(getPaths(obj[k], sofar.concat([k])));
  });

  return paths;
}

console.log(getPaths(obj));

// Output:
// [ [ 'A', 'B', 'e' ],
//   [ 'A', 'B', 'f', 'g' ],
//   [ 'A', 'B', 'f', 'h' ],
//   [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'i' ],
//   [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'j' ],
//   [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'k' ],
//   [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'l' ],
//   [ 'A', 'B', 'D', 'm' ],
//   [ 'A', 'B', 'D', 'n' ],
//   [ 'A', 'B', 'D', 'o' ],
//   [ 'A', 'B', 'D', 'p' ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array for the visited nodes and use it as part of the result.

```js
function getPath(object, path) {
    path = path || [];
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
        if (object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object') {
            return getPath(object[key], path.concat(key));
        }
        console.log(path.concat([key,object[key]]).join('/'));
    });
}

var data = { A: { B: { e: "1", f: { g: "2", h: "3" }, C: { i: "4", j: "5", k: "6", l: "7" }, D: { m: "8", n: "9", o: "10", p: "11" } } } };
getPath(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the return statement from the code makes it work for me.

https://jsbin.com/deqelaj/edit?html,js,console

```
var assets = [];

function build(json, path, assets){
for (var elem in json) {
  if(json.hasOwnProperty(elem)){
    if(json[elem] == 0){
        assets.push(elem);

          //do stuff with the array


       assets.pop();

      } else {
        var parent = path + '/' + elem;
        assets.push(parent);
        console.log(assets)
        build(json[elem], parent, assets);
      }
    }
   }
  }


var json = {
  "A": {
        "B": {
            "e": "",
            "f": {
                "g": "",
                "h": ""
            },
            "C": {
                "i": "",
                "j": "",
                "k": "",
                "l": ""
            },
            "D": {
                "m": "",
                "n": "",
                "o": "",
                "p": ""
            }
        }
    }
  }


build(json, '', assets);

console.log(assets)
```

Comment: It works up to a certain point, check https://jsbin.com/wifiyagoga/edit?html,js,console it adds elements that are not it's parents in the last steps, with the return statement this is fixed, however it does not build the array for every element.

Comment: Update: I think removing return and adding assets.pop(); after build(json[elem], parent, assets); solves it

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it using `reduce` and `concat`

```js
const build = (data, path = []) =>
  data == null
    ? []
    : Object (data) === data
      ? Object.entries (data) .reduce ((acc, [ k, v ]) =>
          acc.concat (build (v, [ ...path, k ])), [])
      : [ [ ...path, data ] ]

const mydata =
  { A: { B: { e: '1'
            , f: { g: '2'
                 , h: '3' 
                 }
            , C: { i: '4'
                 , j: '5'
                 , k: '6'
                 , l: '7'
                 }
            , D: { m: '8'
                 , n: '9'
                 , o: '10'
                 , p: '11'
                 } 
            }
       }
  }

console.log (build (mydata))
// [ ['A','B','e','1'],
//   ['A','B','f','g','2'],
//   ['A','B','f','h','3'],
//   ['A','B','C','i','4'],
//   ['A','B','C','j','5'],
//   ['A','B','C','k','6'],
//   ['A','B','C','l','7'],
//   ['A','B','D','m','8'],
//   ['A','B','D','n','9'],
//   ['A','B','D','o','10'],
//   ['A','B','D','p','11'] ]
```